# Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04 Kernel question

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, driver, ubuntu-20.04, ubuntu-22.04

so I did the upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04.

On the 5.15.0-47 Kernel I'm not able to unlock the encrypted disk.

On the 5.13.0-40, I'm able to unlock but don't have any drivers. From ethernet over wifi to webcam and microphone etc.

I have no idea what is going on to be honest, nor how to fix this.

Any help is really appreciated :)

Comment: Wrong keyboard layout? it was always a mess with ubuntu for non default layouts.

Comment: No layout was correct, i was able to see my password going the way over the boot menu somewhere. Anyway I reinstalled 20.04. I think it has something to do with LUKS and not sharing the password between kernels or something. Im not sure